# jqgrid get rowData values without selecting multi-select checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jgrid with multiple rows and 5 columns without check-boxes. In 5th column it has screen permissions. I had given the sample of jqgrid below. 
[image]
So when i am changing screen permissions either by clicking on the close mark or clicking on plus mark i am deleting existing or adding other available permissions to the screen.
Here i am doing same operation for multiple rows in grid. When i am clicking on the SAVE button outside of the grid i need to get the edited row values and need to send back to controller.

I tried this functionality with the `selarrow` function of jqgrid. but i am not getting these edited row values without selecting the checkbox of the row.

Could any one help me how to get this edited row values without selecting the checkboxes of the row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
            var lastSel;
            jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid({
              ...
             onSelectRow: function(id){ 
               if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
                 jQuery(this).restoreRow(lastSel); 
                 lastSel=id; 
                 } 
              jQuery(this).editRow(id, true); 
               },
               ...
              });
```

onSelectRow :Raised immediately after row was clicked. 
rowid:  is the id of the row,
status: is the status of the selection,
e: is the event object. Can be used when multiselect is set to true. true if the row is selected, false if the row is deselected.

You Can refer this as well:
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Comment: Thanks for your response @Vivek Munshi.. Sorry if my question is not understand. But I am looking for some different like without selection of row. I am changing the cell values in multiple rows and when I m clicking on save I need to get those edited row values.